# How can i solve a Math error between decimal and double?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
return Math.Ceiling((_BytesReceived / _TotalBytesToReceive) * 100);
```

_BytesReceived is int and also _TotalBytesToReceive is int.

The error is:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Math.Ceiling(decimal)' and 'Math.Ceiling(double)'   DownloadMultipleFiles

The full function:

```
public int ProgressPercentage
    {
        get
        {
            if (_TotalBytesToReceive > 0)
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((_BytesReceived / (double)_TotalBytesToReceive) * 100d));
            }
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what happens when you type  `100m` at the end instead of just 100

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik i'm getting then this error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) DownloadMultipleFiles

Comment: You need to cast one of the two numbers to double, you are going to always get 0 as an answer if you don't (it also fixes your problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
return (int)Math.Ceiling((double)(
   (double)_BytesReceived / (double)_TotalBytesToReceive * 100.0d
));
```

or if you prefer `float`:

```
return (int)Math.Ceiling((float)(
   (float)BytesReceived / (float)_TotalBytesToReceive * 100.0f
));
```

The reason is, that Math.Ceil is overloaded, accepting `float` and `double`. Your expression needs to be cast to the target type, the compiler just wants to know, what type it should cast to, because both is possible.

Be aware that when using `float`, the additional typecast in the beginning may still be necessary (did not try that one out).

Comment: `((double)_BytesReceived) / _TotalBytesToReceive` would be a better choice. $20 says the op's next question would be why does he always get 0 (he is doing int division). Casting one of the two numbers to a double or a float before the division solves both problems.

Comment: The code is still wrong, you need to get rid of the `( )` surrounding the `/` operation and make the cast happen first.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Too late today

Comment: @Psi still getting the error Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) after your last edit.

Comment: That's a different error, now I'm going to cast everything explicitly. If this doesn't work, I will quit programming for today.

Comment: Still same error Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) sorry.

Comment: Wait, you are returning. Your function is not returning an `int`, is it? Adding a cast back.

Comment: @Psi it does return int. I added the whole function code to my question. Edited my question with the full function.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should convert all your variables into int or what you want for example :

`Convert.Toint32(value);`
`Convert.ToDouble(value);`

and so on

Comment: This seems to solve the error: return Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((_BytesReceived / (double)_TotalBytesToReceive) * 100d)); But should i convert toint32 or 64 ?

Comment: convert ToInt32() ... p.s if you find this helpful please mark as solution or upvote

Comment: @Muj he says : 

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS0121 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Math.Ceiling(decimal)' and 'Math.Ceiling(double)' DownloadMultipleFiles , so convert all to int